# php array adding key to array to make new array not getting

Tags: php, arrays

I have arrays as follows:

```
$A = ["a","b","c"];
$B = ["1" , "2", "3"];
```

I am trying to create an array as follows:

```
Array(["test"] => "a"
      "val"=>1),
    (["test"] => "b"
      "val"=>2),
   (["test"] => "c"
      "val"=>3)
```

I did something like this:

```
$data =array();


for($i=0;$i<count($A);$i++){

$data["test"]  = $A[$i] ;
$data['val']  = $B[$i] ;

}
```

But I am getting only the last value in resultant array as:

```
Array(["test"] => "c"
          "val"=>3)
```

The first two elements missing. please help me.

Answer (score 2):

you code is rewrite values of array every time loop execute.so you have to create multidimensional array.this will show you data as you want..

```
 $data =array();


    for($i=0;$i<count($A);$i++){

    $data[]  = array('test' =>$A[$i],'val'=>$B[$i]) ;


    }
```

Comment: thanks @KevinBrown next time i will be careful with that

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_map` function as

```
$result = array_map(function($a,$b){return ['test' => $a,'val' => $b];},$A,$B);
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You just overwriten the value of $data['test'] and $data['val']. It should be a 2 dimentional array and The following code should solve your issue mate..

```
$A = ["a", "b", "c"];
$B = ["1", "2", "3"];

$data = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($A); $i++) {

    $data[$i]['test'] = $A[$i];
    $data[$i]['val'] = $B[$i];
}
```

Comment: I have explained the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`$data["test"]` and `$data["test"]` are being overwritten. You need to make them array.

Try

```
$A = ["a","b","c"];
$B = ["1","2","3"];

for($i=0;$i<count($A);$i++)
{
    $data[$i]["test"] = $A[$i];
    $data[$i]['val'] = $B[$i];
}

print_r($data);
```

Comment: its just identical to mine !!